# How to auto increment a column so the value increases by 1 when a new item is added using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to auto increment a column called order so when a new item is added it increments by 1, I have tried using the `autoIncrement()` method when editing my column but run into an error when I apply this **Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'order'** is there a way to use `autoIncrement()` or is there another way this can be done? Thank you.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('order')->unsigned()->default(1)->autoIncrement()->change();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why you need that? By default `id` field is an auto increament field

Comment: Auto increment columns are reserved for primary keys which have have to be unique. It doesn't make sense to have a PK with a default value because the default value should never be used.

Comment: Also, `order` is a reserved word for mysql and Laravel suggests naming your PKs `id`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: When multiple images are uploaded I want each image to have different order number, by incrementing by 1 otherwise they will all have the same value.

Comment: `insert into images (pk, user_id, image_data, order) (select null, '<user_id>', '<image_data>', max(order) +1 from images where user_id = '<user_id>') group by user_id` You could do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two auto-incrementing columns? That way lies madness.

Set your `order` column to default to a number, eg: `1`, and only modify it if you want to set something's ordering to be custom. Use order as your primary sort key, and `id` or `timestamp` as the secondary.

Laravel doesn't support this because databases don't generally support it. The `increments()` and `bigIncrements()` column types cannot be used multiple times in the same table Schema and will fail on create:

Comment: The table already exists so adding bigIncrements wouldn't work since that is applied to the ID.

Comment: Ok how would I approach that? Would something like this work in the store function.
`$image = Images::find(['id']);
 $image->increment('order');
`

Comment: @BrandonK, yes, this will increase your `order` on selected raw.